# Flutter TextScaler has no inverse

Tags: flutter, user-interface, text, accessibility, scaling

After the recent deprecation of `textScaleFactor` and the introduction of `TextScaler` as an alternative one may find oneself faced with the following problem: Previously one could use the multiplicative inverse of the `textScaleFactor` to reverse the effect of very large scaling (e.g. from accessibility settings in iOS system settings), but this is no longer possible since the nonlinear function `TextScaler.scale` in general does not have an inverse (in the linear case, of course, it does).

While this maybe sounds like a theoretical problem, there are practical applications. Say you use a widget that displays multiple texts (potentially of different sizes) and which does not expose the `TextScaler` of the single texts, but their `TextStyle`. If you want to limit scaling in one of the texts only (and thus wrapping the widget with `MediaQuery` containing a clamped copy of the `TextScaler` is no option), you could previously calculate the allowable scaling factor and then pass `fontSize` times some correction factor to the respective `TextStyle`, which now after the introduction of `TextScaler` doesn't work.

To be even more concrete, the example could be:

```
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "very, very, very long label text",
                labelStyle: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 16.0 / MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
                    ),
              ),
            )
```

Any thoughts on how to migrate such workarounds to the use of `TextScaler` instead of `textScaleFactor`?

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for a better answer, but I wanted to show a workaround that a colleague suggested. I'd say it's not pretty, but it works and is an effective solution.

The idea is to replace the potentially nonlinear `TextScaler` with a linear one whose `textScaleFactor` is determined by scaling the most important font size of the widget below (e.g. the font size of the input text of the `TextField` in the example). The linear `TextScaler` is then invertible and the workaround for sizing texts individually via their `TextStyle` continues to work.

```
      Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        double mainFontSize =
            16; // actually get this from the main textStyle of the widget below?
        double textScaleFactor =
            MediaQuery.textScalerOf(context).scale(mainFontSize) / mainFontSize;
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            textScaler: TextScaler.linear(textScaleFactor),
          ),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "very, very, very long label text",
              labelStyle: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 16.0 / textScaleFactor,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```